# Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException when I use a string s

Tags: json

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException:“After parsing a value an unexpected character was encountered:

Newtonsoft.Json version="11.0.2"
in c#4.5

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<QueryModel>(Json);
  private class QueryModel
    {
        public Pagination pagination { get; set; }
        public string queryJson { get; set; }
    }

public class Pagination
{   
    public int rows { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
   }
```

when I use json
"{"pagination":{"rows":10,"page":1},"queryJson":"{}"}" is ok

but use

"{"pagination":{"rows":10,"page":1},"queryJson":\"{/\"keyword/\":/\"test/\"}\"}"
is error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sub JsonStr use '' replace \"\"   like "{"pagination":{"rows":10,"page":1},"queryJson":\"{'keyword':'test'}\"}"